# Perforce - How to remove a file from a shelved changelist?

Tags: version-control, perforce, unshelve

I had added a bunch of new files into a new changelist using *p4 add* command. I shelved the changelist for review purpose (swarm server picks the changes from shelved changelist).

During code review, I was told to remove a file from the changelist. I did the following steps to achieve the same

1. First, unshelve the changelist

   `p4 unshelve -c (cl-number)`
2. Reverted the file that I had added previously

   `p4 revert (file)`

Perforce says "....../file - was add, abandoned"

3. Again, shelve the files back

   `p4 shelve -f -c (cl-number)`

Now, if I see ***p4 change (cl-number)***, the file that I deleted is not visible in the files mentioned below. However, if I do ***p4 describe -s -S (cl-number)***, the removed file is still visible and not being removed from shelve.

What should be done to remove a specific file in a shelved changelist?

Answer (score 11):

You need to run `p4 shelve -d -c (cl-number) (file)`.

See also `p4 help shelve`.

Comment: Just want to add on top, in case such shelved changelist is submitted and associated with swarm review. We still have to do `p4 shelve -f -c (cl-number)` in order to update associated swarm review with our shelved changelist as well. Anyway, your solution also works especially whenever we need to remove individual files. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This is an option that's pretty close to what you tried:

```
p4 unshelve -c (cl-number)
p4 revert (file)
p4 shelve -r -c (cl-number)
```

The "-r" flag causes the entire shelf to be replaced with what's in your workspace, rather than adding what's in your workspace to the shelf (and leaving other shelved files untouched).